# Windows 10 Creator Updates failing with 0x80004005 Error

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I've been unable to install Windows 10 creator updates on an Acer Veriton X6610.   Here's a dump from system info for the machine...

```
OS Name    Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version    10.0.15063 Build 15063
Other OS Description     Not Available
OS Manufacturer    Microsoft Corporation
System Name    MICK-PC2017
System Manufacturer    Acer
System Model    Veriton X6610G
System Type    x64-based PC
System SKU    To be filled by O.E.M.
Processor    Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 3401 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date    Acer P01-B0, 10/08/2011
SMBIOS Version    2.7
Embedded Controller Version    255.255
BIOS Mode    Legacy
BaseBoard Manufacturer    Acer
BaseBoard Model    Not Available
BaseBoard Name    Base Board
Platform Role    Workstation
Secure Boot State    Unsupported
PCR7 Configuration    Binding Not Possible
Windows Directory    C:\Windows
System Directory    C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device    \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Locale    Australia
Hardware Abstraction Layer    Version = "10.0.15063.850"
User Name    TONICSYSTEMS\mick
Time Zone    AUS Eastern Daylight Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM)    24.0 GB
Total Physical Memory    23.9 GB
Available Physical Memory    15.9 GB
Total Virtual Memory    34.9 GB
Available Virtual Memory    26.0 GB
Page File Space    11.0 GB
Page File    C:\pagefile.sys
Device Encryption Support    Reasons for failed automatic device encryption: PCR7 binding is not supported, Hardware Security Test Interface failed and device is not InstantGo, Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected, TPM is not usable
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    Yes
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions    Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware    Yes
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection    Yes
```

This machine is about 5 years old. Whilst there are no issues doing a clean install from an ISO for Windows 10, none of the past "Creator updates" have succeeded.  Nor can I manually upgrade the system from an ISO.

For past creator updates I've resolved this issue by simply doing a fresh install from an ISO for the creator update.

The following is a link to a zip file containing logs from the C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\ folder

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmKXLr_eXls3k0BvmHsmxuE1c71I

This has become a much bigger issue as Microsoft now seems to sending out these updates every 6 months instead of every year now.  Plus the system's prompting to start update have become much more problematic, repeatedly asking you to pick a time when you have already selected a time in the future and sometimes giving you limited options on delaying the update.

EDIT: Event Log entry contains....

```
Fault bucket 128033362033, type 5
Event Name: WinSetupDiag02
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: 1
P2: 2
P3: 9
P4: 1
P5: 0x80004005
P6: 0x50015
P7: 15063
P8: rs2_release
P9: 16299
P10: rs3_release

Attached files:
\\?\C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\SetupAct.log
\\?\C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\diagerr.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERC1D6.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERC19A.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERC1BA.tmp.txt

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\NonCritical_1_6db14e0451333502ba4d48798d4e849a61d3b4_00000000_4603c737

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 918aa387-154a-4008-81dc-6b7c24582e58
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed bucket: c52536445b66d0192c98ee8bd0f86913
```

The tail of the setupact.log is...

```
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  CONX   ConX::Compatibility::CCompatibilityHost::SetCorrelationVector:(wsc:setup:): Correlation Vector [bb8efTW1cU2JS2tG.999.23.5.0]
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  CONX   ConX::Compatibility::CCompatibilityHost::SetCorrelationVector:(wsc:wica:): Correlation Vector [bb8efTW1cU2JS2tG.999.23.6.0]
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  CONX   Compatibility Finalize called
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  SP     SetupPlatform opted-in to sqm
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: Upload telemetry data
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  MOUPG  Finalize: Remapping install error [0x80004005] -> [0xC1900108] for telemetry.
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  MOUPG  Finalize: Reporting result value: [0xC1900108]
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  MOUPG  CSetupDiagnostics: Tracing Data [DWORD] -> [Setup360MappedResult]=[0xC1900108] [8f08e3e8-5e7e-4dc3-a037-2c454c952ef4][51a8edc8-8eec-4e39-92b5-c92c7d8990f8][][0x1]
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  MOUPG  CSetupDiagnostics: Tracing Data [DWORD] -> [Setup360Result]=[0x80004005] [8f08e3e8-5e7e-4dc3-a037-2c454c952ef4][51a8edc8-8eec-4e39-92b5-c92c7d8990f8][][0x1]
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  MOUPG  CSetupDiagnostics: Tracing Data [DWORD] -> [Setup360Extended]=[0x50015] [8f08e3e8-5e7e-4dc3-a037-2c454c952ef4][51a8edc8-8eec-4e39-92b5-c92c7d8990f8][][0x1]
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  MOUPG  CSetupDiagnostics: Tracing Data [CUSTOM] -> [WindowsUpdateExit] -> [Win10UA:VNL:URL:9252:<1.4.9200.22334>:<1>:{904F4934-3283-4014-A303-E669EB09BB9D}:[10.0.15063]:[2]][8f08e3e8-5e7e-4dc3-a037-2c454c952ef4][51a8edc8-8eec-4e39-92b5-c92c7d8990f8][][0x1]
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  MOUPG  CSetupDiagnostics: Tracing Data [CUSTOM] -> [Downlevel] -> [Win10UA:VNL:URL:9252:<1.4.9200.22334>:<1>:{904F4934-3283-4014-A303-E669EB09BB9D}:[10.0.15063]:[2]][8f08e3e8-5e7e-4dc3-a037-2c454c952ef4][51a8edc8-8eec-4e39-92b5-c92c7d8990f8][f3ebf6fe-f27f-4647-ad88-b82daf29be44][][Failed][Windows 10 Pro][15063][1][2][0x80004005][0x50015][16299]
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  MOUPG  Finalize: Retrieving downlevel ticks from registry...
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  MOUPG  Finalize: Converting [504] downlevel ticks to seconds...
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  MOUPG  Finalize: Reporting total downlevel time: [2520 seconds]
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  MOUPG  CSetupDiagnostics: Tracing Data [DWORD] -> [Setup360DownlevelTime]=[0x9D8] [8f08e3e8-5e7e-4dc3-a037-2c454c952ef4][51a8edc8-8eec-4e39-92b5-c92c7d8990f8][][0x1]
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: Releasing NewSystem object...
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                         Set Watson bucketing parameter #3 to 1
2018-01-24 17:30:19, Info                  SP     CDeploymentBase::CleanupMounts: Unmounting directory C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SafeOS\SafeOS.Mount
[17292] Received unmount request for image with guid 67fd60f9-f33c-41b2-bbb6-5943a9b29cd8.
[17292] Unmount for image at C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SafeOS\SafeOS.Mount complete.
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  SP     Persist diagnostics data for new system for future uploading
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Persisting diagnostics data to C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Diagnostics\diagnostics.dat
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Diagnostics data saved successfully
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Warning               SP     SPUninitializeNetwork: Not running in Windows PE; will not try to uninitialize network
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  SP     OPERATIONTRACK: CNewSystem Release
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: NewSystem object released!
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: Releasing Setup Platform object...
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  SP     Releasing the setup platform
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  SP       StopTelemetry: 1
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  SP       UploadTelemetryData: 1
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  SP       CorrelationVector: bb8efTW1cU2JS2tG.999.26
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  SP     Try to merge diagnostics data from default new system data file
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Initializing diagnostics helper; data file = C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Diagnostics\diagnostics.dat
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Found existing diagnostics data, attempting to load it.
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Merging diagnostics data for WatsonBucket
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Merging diagnostics data success
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  SP     Finish merge diagnostics data
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  SP     Start uploading diagnostics data for setup platform
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER DiagERInitialize:Entry Also Initialized the log
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER IDiagER::IDiagER:Entry
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::Initialize:Entry
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::Initialize:Entry
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER Consent Value = HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\Consent!WinSetupDiag02 has been set to 4
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Failed to get watson parameter override. Hr=[0x80070002]
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Failed to get watson parameter override. Hr=[0x80070002]
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Failed to get watson parameter override. Hr=[0x80070002]
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Failed to get watson parameter override. Hr=[0x80070002]
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Failed to get watson parameter override. Hr=[0x80070002]
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Failed to get watson parameter override. Hr=[0x80070002]
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Failed to get watson parameter override. Hr=[0x80070002]
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Failed to get watson parameter override. Hr=[0x80070002]
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Failed to get watson parameter override. Hr=[0x80070002]
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Failed to get watson parameter override. Hr=[0x80070002]
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Warning                      Failed to delete watson parameter overrides. Hr=[0x80070002]
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Watson Bucketing Parameters[0] = 1
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Watson Bucketing Parameters[1] = 2
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Watson Bucketing Parameters[2] = 9
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Watson Bucketing Parameters[3] = 1
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Watson Bucketing Parameters[4] = 0x80004005
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Watson Bucketing Parameters[5] = 0x50015
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Watson Bucketing Parameters[6] = 15063
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Watson Bucketing Parameters[7] = rs2_release
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Watson Bucketing Parameters[8] = 16299
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         Watson Bucketing Parameters[9] = rs3_release
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER DiagERAddBucketingParameters:Entry
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::AddBucketingParameters:Entry
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER IDiagER::AddBucketingParameters:Entry
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::AddBucketingParameters:Adding bucketing param=1
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::AddBucketingParameters:Adding bucketing param=2
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::AddBucketingParameters:Adding bucketing param=9
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::AddBucketingParameters:Adding bucketing param=1
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::AddBucketingParameters:Adding bucketing param=0x80004005
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::AddBucketingParameters:Adding bucketing param=0x50015
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::AddBucketingParameters:Adding bucketing param=15063
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::AddBucketingParameters:Adding bucketing param=rs2_release
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::AddBucketingParameters:Adding bucketing param=16299
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::AddBucketingParameters:Adding bucketing param=rs3_release
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER DiagERSetHeader:Entry
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::SetHeader:Entry
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER IDiagER::SetHeader:Entry
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::SetHeader:Setting header=Microsoft Windows Installation encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         CDiagnosticsHelper::GetWatsonFilesToAttach: Attaching file C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\SetupAct.log
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                         CDiagnosticsHelper::GetWatsonFilesToAttach: Attaching file C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\diagerr.xml
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER DiagERAddFiles:Entry
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::AddFiles:Entry
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER IDiagER::AddFiles:Entry
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::AddFiles:Adding file=C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\SetupAct.log
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::AddFiles:Adding file=C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\diagerr.xml
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER DiagERSubmitEx:Entry
2018-01-24 17:30:33, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::Submit:Entry
2018-01-24 17:30:35, Info                  DIAGER Watson Error Report submitted and Result=2
2018-01-24 17:30:35, Info                  DIAGER DiagERTerminate:Entry
2018-01-24 17:30:35, Info                  DIAGER CWfpER::~CWfpER:Entry
2018-01-24 17:30:35, Info                  DIAGER Consent Value = HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\Consent!WinSetupDiag02 has been cleaned out
2018-01-24 17:30:35, Info                  DIAGER IDiagER::~IDiagER:Entry
2018-01-24 17:30:35, Info                         Key CollectTrace is not available.
2018-01-24 17:30:35, Info                         Copy telemetry file: source folder: C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther, destination folder: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Diagnosis\ETLLogs
2018-01-24 17:30:35, Info                         Copy etl files: source: C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\DlTel-Merge.etl, destination: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Diagnosis\ETLLogs\DlTel-Merge.etl
2018-01-24 17:30:35, Info                         Copy etl files: source: C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\DlTel-Merge1.etl, destination: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Diagnosis\ETLLogs\DlTel-Merge1.etl
2018-01-24 17:30:35, Info                         pCopyTelemetryFile: Wrote CV bb8efTW1cU2JS2tG.999.26 to ETL C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Diagnosis\ETLLogs\DlTel-Merge1.etl:$ETLUNIQUECVDATA
2018-01-24 17:30:35, Info                         Diagtrack service is running
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                         Successfully Forceuploaded the telemetry data.
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                         Upload files successfully so we can remove all etl files.
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  SP     Closing Panther Logging
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: Setup Platform object released!
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  Finalize: Leaving Execute Method
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Warning               MOUPG  CSetupDiagnostics::ReportData - Not reporting WINDLP data point [0x2004]
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Warning               MOUPG  CSetupDiagnostics::ReportData - Not reporting WINDLP data point [0x2003]
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Warning               MOUPG  CSetupDiagnostics::ReportData - Not reporting WINDLP data point [0x2001]
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  ProgressHandlerAction: Sending final progress message for action [0].
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  ProgressHandlerAction FinalUpdate: 0x0, 0x0 / 0x0, 0x0
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  ProgressHandlerAction: Sending final progress message for action [0].
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  ProgressHandlerAction FinalUpdate: 0x0, 0x0 / 0x0, 0x0
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  Waiting for actions thread to exit.
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  Actions thread has exited.
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Warning               MOUPG  CSetupDiagnostics::ReportData - Not reporting WINDLP data point [0x2004]
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Warning               MOUPG  CSetupDiagnostics::ReportData - Not reporting WINDLP data point [0x2000]
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Warning               MOUPG  CSetupDiagnostics::ReportData - Not reporting WINDLP data point [0x3000]
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  DlpTask: Leaving Execute Method
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  SetupNotify: Specifying extended data [0x50015] for error [0x80004005].
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  SetupHost: Reporting error event -> [0x80004005, 0x50015]
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Warning               MOUPG  SetupNotify::ReportEvent - Report ID or Event Reporter not available.
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  SetupManager: FailureCount = [8]
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  SetupManager: Requesting cleanup level [0x2] from parent process.
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  Setup phase change: [SetupPhaseError] -> [SetupPhaseUnpack]
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  SetupManager: Deleting task: [Prepare]...
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  SetupManager: Deleting task: [Install]...
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  SetupManager: Deleting task: [Exit]...
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  SetupManager: Found unpack task! Restarting layout action...
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::Execute(237): Result = 0x80004005
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(375): Result = 0x80004005
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  CONX   Uninitializing compatibility provider wsc:setup:...
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  CONX   Uninitializing compatibility provider wsc:wica:...
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  SetupUI: Calling PowerClearRequest with type [0x1]...
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  SetupUI: Power request cleared!
2018-01-24 17:30:37, Info                  MOUPG  **************** SetupHost Logging End ****************
```

Comment: It's not really a solution.  I've changed the windows update settings to delay the updates as described here https://www.windowscentral.com/how-delay-windows-10-fall-creators-update-while-still-getting-security-patches

Comment: This was advice I received after a lengthy chat with Microsoft Support.  I'll either wait until they diagnose and find a solution for the issue or later on in the year do a fresh install.  In the mean time I've been assured I'll continue to receive updates for 1703

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to TPM. Your TPM chip not compatible.

You are required to have a TPM 2.0 model and not a TPM 1.2.

Device Encryption requires InstantGo/Connected Standby certification, which requires TPM 2.0 (and is not supported by 1.2).

So don't use TPM at all and you'll be fine.

Comment: That's almost an answer. However as far as I'm aware I'm not using TPM.  I can see in the BIOS settings that TPM Support is set to Enabled, but the TPM State is set to Disabled.  What are you suggesting exactly?

Comment: Are you using any type of encryption ? If you do, you won't be able to upgrade. If you don't use any, disable TPM and then the upgrade should work.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. BitLocker is off on all drives.  I have run cipher /s on all the drives and all the files come back with U not E

Comment: Then turn it off in the UEFI and see if the patch works.

Comment: I don't exactly understand.  Are you suggesting I should change TPM Support setting in the BIOS to Disabled?

Comment: Yes, try installing the update with TPM disabled. If you don't use anything that uses it, there's no reason it should be on.

Comment: I've tried installing with TPM Support disabled in the bios ... Same result.

Comment: I upvoted you as a thanks for the help.... but alas it's not the answer.

Comment: It's kind of strange. If you don't have anything using it, the update should work with TPM disabled. If something uses it (as the patching seems to indicate), then that thing should stop working when TPM is disabled. Something does not add-up. It's an interesting case to dig deeper into.